# troubleshoot active choice reactive reference parameter in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

I am facing issues with active choice and reactive choice parameter groovy script in jenkins.
Existing groovy script which was working previously, now has the issue as a result I cannot pass the input correctly within the job.
Is there a possible way to troubleshoot this groovy as we don't have any IDE and jenkins compile those scripts internally.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about the script console at https://your-jenkins-server/script ?

Comment: does it appears in manage jenkins?

Comment: it requires admin privileges in my env. Can't I do without https://your-jenkins-server/script is there a way?

Comment: It does appear in manage Jenkins down at the bottom. Script Console.